# Why does the conditional statement in SwiftUI combine multiple views into one inside a `NavigationView`?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a menu list in the first column inside a navigation view, and the content of the second column and subsequent columns in the view would change based on the selected menu item in the first column.

After I added the corresponding views under the conditional statement, which is used to detect which menu item is selected, inconsistent behavior appeared. The views are rendered as a single view, creating a two-column layout. **It suppose to be a three-column layout.**

It seems that when I put two separate views under one conditional statement, SwiftUI treats the views under the condition as a single view (code snippet 1). This resulted in the view being laid out as if it were inside a vertical stack, instead of two separate views. So, the end result is a two-column layout, but it is supposed to have three columns like what could be achieved with code snippet 2.

Am I missing anything here?

**Code Snippet 1:**

```
        NavigationView {
            MainMenuView(
                selectedMenu: $mainMenuViewModel.selectedMenuId,
                menuGroups: mainMenuViewModel.menuGroups,
            )
            .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)

            if mainMenuViewModel.selectedMenuId == .wordlists {
                WordlistsView()
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)
                
                Text("Wordlist Details")
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_DETAIL)
            } else {
                Text("Words")
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)
                
                Text("Word Details")
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)
            }
        }
```

**Code Snippet 2:**

```
        NavigationView {
            MainMenuView(
                selectedMenu: $mainMenuViewModel.selectedMenuId,
                menuGroups: mainMenuViewModel.menuGroups,
            )
            .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)

            if mainMenuViewModel.selectedMenuId == .wordlists {
                WordlistsView()
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)
            } else {
                Text("Words")
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)
            }
            
            if mainMenuViewModel.selectedMenuId == .wordlists {
                Text("Wordlist Details")
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_DETAIL)
            } else {
                Text("Word Details")
                    .frame(minWidth: Self.WIDTH_COLUMN)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well yeah, that is intended behaviour. Since you already have Code Snippet 2, I assume you are only asking for why this is the case?

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper. I suspected this is intended behavior, but I wonder if I can simplify the logic with something like code snippet 1.

Answer (score 1):

All the relevant information is documented in the "[the result builder transform](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md#the-result-builder-transform)" section of the result builder SE proposal, as well as the documentation page of [`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder), which is the result builder used to build `body`.

`NavigationView` seems to determine whether it should be a two-column layout or a three-column by looking at the type of view your `ViewBuilder` closure returns. If it is a `TupleView<(C1, C2)>`, then it is a two-column layout. If it is `TupleView<(C1, C2, C3)>`, then it is a three column layout.

Juxtaposing n views in a view builder calls the `ViewBuilder.buildBlock` overload that has n parameters. From the signature of `buildBlock`, we can see that this returns a `TupleView<T>` where `T` is an n-tuple.

An if-else statement in a view builder is translated into an if-else statement that calls `buildEither(first:)` in the true branch, and `buildEither(second:)` in the false branch. Whichever branch is chosen, the return value of `buildEither` is then used in other `buildBlock` calls.

When you write:

```
View1()
if condition {
    View2()
    View3()
} else {
    View4()
    View5()
}
```

The generated code is effectively this:

```
let var1 = View1()
let var2: _ConditionalContent<TupleView<(View2, View3)>, TupleView<(View4, View5)>>
if condition {
    let var3 = ViewBuilder.buildBlock(View2(), View3())
    var2 = ViewBuilder.buildEither(first: var3)
} else {
    let var4 = ViewBuilder.buildBlock(View4(), View5())
    var2 = ViewBuilder.buildEither(second: var4)
}
return ViewBuilder.buildBlock(var1, var2)
```

Notice that this returns a

```
TupleView<(
    View1, 
    _ConditionalContent<
        TupleView<(View2, View3)>, 
        TupleView<(View4, View5)>
    >
)>
```

This is a `TupleView<T>` where `T` is only a 2-tuple! Hence, the navigation view is 2-column. The views in the inner `TupleView`s are automatically laid out in some default manner. In this case, they happen to be laid out vertically.

On the other hand, if you have two if statements like in Code Snippet 2, the final view's type would be

```
TupleView<(
    View1, 
    _ConditionalContent<View2, View3>,
    _ConditionalContent<View4, View5>
)>
```

where `T` is a 3-tuple.

Note that `NavigationView` is deprecated, perhaps partly because of this confusing behaviour. Now, you should use [`NavigationSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview), which has different initialisers for creating 2-columns and 3-columns. But in any case, you do need 2 if statements.

Technically, you can build the view without using the syntactic sugar of a `ViewBuilder` (i.e. directly calling `buildBlock`, `buildEither` etc), then you would only use one if statement. but I cannot imagine how tedious that would be :)

Comment: I tried the new `NavigationSplitView`, but it could not hide the sidebar toggle button from the toolbar. That's why I am still using `NavigationView`.